# Get live location update even application is not in background(iPhone)

Tags: ios, iphone, background, location, core-location

As much as I know it's not possible to get location update, if application is not running in background, but today my boss shows me an Application 'Life360' which is used to get user location even when application is terminated. I searched a lot on this but couldn't find anything .Can anyone please help me on this .How 'Life360' get user location if app is terminated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Location update can wake up your app in the background (if it is terminated). You must activate "Location Updates" in Capabilities's background mode. Then use this code: `self.locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()`. This will wake up your app each time it detect location changes. You may want to consult [User's Location Update Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html) for in-depth information.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, but they are saying it shouldn't depend upon the movement because it fires when user travel at least 500 meters .Is there any other way to get location before user travel's upto 500 meters.Please help me if you can.